# Spring Batch SimpleJobOperator can stop the executionId retrieved by the method getRunningExecutions

Tags: spring-batch

I am using the jobOperator to stop running executions. The below is my sample code.

```
    Set<Long> executionIds = jobOperator.getRunningExecutions(updateHistoryPriceJob.getName());
    for(Long executionId: executionIds){
        jobOperator.stop(executionId);
    }
```

But it throws the following exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobExecutionNotRunningException: JobExecution must be running so that it can be stopped: JobExecution: id=495, version=2, startTime=2017-05-09 19:11:15.759, endTime=null, lastUpdated=2017-05-09 23:20:18.583, status=STOPPING, exitStatus=exitCode=UNKNOWN;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=495, version=0, Job=[updateHistoryPriceJob]], jobParameters=[{date=1494328275738}]
```

I found that getRunningExecutions would retrieve execution which end time is null while stop would check the batchStatus.

Answer (score 1):

Do your lookup with `JobExplorer` and call `findRunningJobExecutions(String jobName)`. It is the underlying call the `JobOperations` was making, but it returns a set of `JobExecutions` rather than just the IDs.

You can then check the status on each execution to make sure it is in a `STARTED` status (and perhaps `STARTING` depending on your use case) before stopping it.

```
String jobName = updateHistoryPriceJob.getName();
Set<JobExecution> executions = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName);
for(JobExecution execution : executions ){
    if (execution.getStatus == BatchStatus.STARTED) {
        jobOperator.stop(execution.getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobExecutionNotRunningException`

code can be refactored like this.

```
Set<JobExecution> jobExecutionsSet= jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName);
            for (JobExecution jobExecution:jobExecutionsSet) {
                if (jobExecution.getStatus()== BatchStatus.STARTED|| jobExecution.getStatus()== BatchStatus.STARTING || jobExecution.getStatus()== BatchStatus.STOPPING){
                    jobOperator.stop(jobExecution.getId());
                    System.out.println("###########Stopped#########");
                }
            }
```